# When to use pack or grid layouts in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, tkinter, ttk

Are there any best practice tips regarding when one should use pack vs. grid for their layouts?

From what I've been reading via google, the concencus seems to be that grid can handle any pack scenario but not vice-versa.

To start the conversation, it appears that one use case that favors grid vs. pack is when one wants to show/hide widgets.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Neither is intrinsically better than the other. Each have strengths and weaknesses. Learn what those are and the choice of which to use becomes obvious.

`grid` is considerably easier to use if you need to lay things out in a grid. `pack` is generally easier to use if all you need to do is put some widgets in a single row or single column. There's a whole lot of gray area in-between where neither is necessarily better than the other.

The other thing to consider is what you said in your question: if you want to show and hide widgets at run-time, `grid` is probably the best choice because of the `grid_remove` method which remembers the values of all of the configured attributes in case you want to re-add the widget.

Personally, my first choice is always to use `pack` because I first learned Tk back when there was no `grid` command. If I can't do it easily in `pack`, or if I'm very clearly laying things out in a grid, I'll use `grid`.

Comment: Thanks. I learned pack first, too, so its been my preference by default. However, in reviewing my code, I think grid may be a more general purpose solution for me going forward.

Answer (score 10):

I always recommend grid over pack for polished applications.  There are only a few edge cases where pack is easier and fits the bill (everything in one row or col).  grid has better "composability" (e.g. megawidgets or gridding elements of gridded elements).  The reasons to prefer grid are the extra fine-tuning options that it provides.  The use of weight (which effects growing and shrinking btw), minsize and maxsize, as well as convenience features like enforcing uniform rows/columns.

A fully gridded app of any size will use (significantly) fewer frames than an equivalent packed app, and have better shrink/expand control over inner elements.

BTW, both pack and grid can show/hide sub-elements, though the syntax differs slightly between the two.  Grid is just slightly better because 'remove' (rather than 'forget') will remember the grid options on the slave widget.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. Like most, I started programming Tkinter using the pack technique because of its simplicity and because most sample Tkinter code seems to use pack. But the more I study the capabilities of the grid layout manager, the more I feel that it is a "better" general purpose layout technique than pack.

Answer (score 3):

I personally just think grid is a lot easier to work with, so I would use that. Of course, you've probably read the one thing you should never do is try to use both <s>at the same time</s> in the same container. Thank you Bryan Oakley for making that distinction.

Comment: @MatrixFron: to be clear: you can use both, just not both in the same container. Within an application you can mix and match them all you want.

Comment: Thanks. Its good to hear of others using grid on a default basis.