# In what cases Tkinter's grid() cannot be mixed with pack()?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to eliminate strange extra space that seems to resist any size tweaking in my layout when using `grid()` alone, but calling in `pack()` sometimes make things worse: The GUI simply disappear entirely!

I read a few eye-opening layout answers from @Bryan Oakley such as:

[When to use pack or grid layouts in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401202/when-to-use-pack-or-grid-layouts-in-tkinter)

and

[Tkinter: grid or pack inside a grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506152/tkinter-grid-or-pack-inside-a-grid/36507919#36507919)

but when I get down to write my own stuff, I still often have troubles.

My understanding:

1. I must have a Frame to fill the `root window`, otherwise there'd be no hope to fill the extra space in the window, however I tweak widgets alone.
2. For all the child widgets sitting inside a common parent `Frame`, I must use either `pack()` or `grid()` but not both.
3. When using `grid()` in a Frame, it's mandatory to specify `Frame.grid_rowconfigure()` and `.grid_columnconfigure()` with non-zero `weight` arguments. Otherwise, nothing would show up.
4. It's thus possible to have the main `Frame` using `pack()`, but its immediate child `Frames` all using `grid()`; Inside each of these child `Frames` on the grid, we could then `pack()` their own child widgets. In other words, we could interleave `grid()` and `pack()` by "regions" or container hierarchy levels, but never mix them in the same container: The only restriction.
5. By a careful weight design, I could fill a horizontal space in a parent `Frame` with a child `Frame` full of widgets laid out horizontally, e.g.,  all widgets use `grid(sticky='nsew')`, and the child `Frame` uses `pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)`.

If my understanding was correct, then I could never figure out why #5 couldn't work for me, e.g., there is always unused extra space towards the right end of my horizontal child `Frame` inside the main `Frame` of the root window.

**UPDATE 2**

I figured it out. #5 didn't work for me because I forgot to specify `.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` in the main `Frame` before using `grid()`. My bad! Case closed.

**UPDATE**

I'm on macOS High Sierra, running python 3.6.4 Homebrew.

Comment: Well, #1 is false - anything you could do in that Frame could just as easily be done directly in the root window.  Debugging tip: (temporarily) give your Frames a distinct border and/or background color, so you can see exactly what their extent is.  Problems with getting widgets to take up space is often actually a problem with the enclosing Frame not taking up space.

Comment: @jasonharper Yeah I always colourize my frames, and mess around with/without frames. Maybe it's macOS.

Comment: @kakyo: no, `pack` and `grid` behave identically on all platforms supported by tkinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In what cases Tkinter's grid() cannot be mixed with pack()?

In all cases, you cannot use both `grid` and `pack` for widgets that have a common master. Within a master, all direct children must use the same geometry manager. Within an application as a whole, you can mix `pack` and `grid` all you want as long as you follow that one rule that you can't use them both for widgets that have the same parent.

> 1. I must have a Frame to fill the root window, otherwise there'd be no hope to fill the extra space in the window, however I tweak widgets alone.

This is not correct. You can easily fill all of the space in the root window without using a frame.

> 2. For all the child widgets sitting inside a common parent Frame, I must use either pack() or grid() but not both.

That is correct. The third option is to use `place`, though it's rarely the best choice.

> 3. When using grid() in a Frame, it's mandatory to specify Frame.grid_rowconfigure() and .grid_columnconfigure() with non-zero weight arguments. Otherwise, nothing would show up.

That is not true -- configuring rows and columns to have a non-zero weight isn't mandatory. It's usually a best practice, but it's not required in order for widgets to show up. The weight only applies to how `grid` manages *extra* space. Any widgets with a non-zero size should appear whether you use weights or not.

> 4. It's thus possible to have the main Frame using pack(), but its immediate child Frames all using grid()

Correct.

> 5. By a careful weight design, I could fill a horizontal space in a parent Frame with a child Frame full of widgets laid out horizontally, e.g., all widgets use grid(sticky='nsew'), and the child Frame uses pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True).

That is correct.